# Tabs not functioning as they should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a simple application which has 2 tabs - `Bio` and `Timeline`, each with their own content. I want to show/hide content based on what I click. My HTML, CSS and JS files are as shown below - 
(https://jsfiddle.net/m25owpse/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tablink').on('click', function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.dashfolio-about' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.about-header-container {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.about-header-container>a {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#bio-dashfolio {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.tablink:active {
  color: red;
}
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
}
.tabcontent.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashbolio-about">

  <div class="about-header-container">
    <a class="bio-header tablink" href="#bio-dashfolio"> Bio </a> 
    <a class="timeline-header tablink" href="#timeline-dashfolio"> Timeline </a> 
  </div>
  <div>
   <div class="tabcontent" id="bio-dashfolio">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed
        vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus. Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit
        diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus. Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
        vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus.
        Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor</p>

    </div>
    <div class="tabcontent" id="timeline-dashfolio">
      <p>Random text is awesome don't you think?!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is however, not doing the trick. I think I'm on the right track, so please help me understand where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you add the active class in your javascript? I think that seems to be missing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$('.dashfolio-about' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

change to:

```
$(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tablink').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $(currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.about-header-container {
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.about-header-container>a {
  padding-right: 10px;
}


#bio-dashfolio {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.tablink:active {
  color: red;
}

.tabcontent {
  display:none;
}

.tabcontent.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class = "dashbolio-about">

    <div class= "about-header-container">
        <a class = "bio-header tablink" href= "#bio-dashfolio"> Bio </a>
        <a class = "timeline-header tablink" href= "#timeline-dashfolio"> Timeline </a>
    </div>

    <div>


        <div class = "tabcontent" id= "bio-dashfolio" >

            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus. Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus. Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor sodales suscipit in in metus. Proin laoreet eros nibh, ut hendrerit diam pharetra at. Morbi id nisi efficitur, vehicula turpis non, tristique sapien. Sed sed vestibulum massa. Vestibulum fringilla tortor id facilisis tempus. Cras consectetur sapien nibhLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vitae diam non dolor  </p>

        </div>

        <div class = "tabcontent" id = "timeline-dashfolio">

            <p> Random text is awesome don't you think?! </p>


        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @gaetanoM, this works perfectly! While I understand why the solution you gave worked, why didn't mine? Doesn't `$('.dashfolio-about' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();` mean it will look through the `.dashfolio-about` div for children with the attribute value selected?

Comment: @KeshavVasudevan Sorry for the delay, you need to add a space: try this:  $('.dashfolio-about    ' + currentAttrValue): this means: select this element (having class dashfolio-about) and then the child "#hhhh". If you don't put a space it means: select an element having id=xxx and class=xxx. This is your mistake. Thanks so much. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! Appreciate the help!